# ZF2 - Validator Context when using Fieldsets

Tags: validation, zend-framework2, fieldset

Is there a way to access the context of a whole form inside a validator of a fieldset-element? It seems the standard behaviour is that the context contains just the form-data of the fieldset where the element resides.

This is my custom validator:

```
/**
 * Returns if the given value is valid
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @param  array   $context
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isValid($value, array $context = array())
{
    $this->setValue($value);

    $bookingId = isset($context['auftrag_buchung_id'])
        ? (int) $context['auftrag_buchung_id']
        : null;

    try {
        $anlieferung = new \DateTime($value);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->error(self::NOT_DATETIME);
        return false;
    }

    try {
        $booking = $this->table->getById($this->user, $bookingId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->error(self::NOT_FOUND);
        return false;
    }

    if (!$this->isInBookingRange($value, $booking)) {
        $this->error(self::NOT_IN_BOOKINGRANGE);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My problem is $context has just the form-data of the fieldset where i configured this validator. But I have to check against a value that is not inside the fieldset

Comment: please post some code so that we can understand better your question.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, the only way I was able to do it, is by adding it to the parent fieldset's element.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to inject the form instance into the validator when assigning the validator to the form using an InputFilter.

```
// 
$form = new \Zend\Form\Form();

/* ..following could be within __construct() Method of the Form object */

// 
$element = new \Zend\Form\Element\Text('text');
$form->add($element);

// 
$inputFilter = new \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter();

// 
$textInput = new \Zend\InputFilter\Input('text');

// Add validator with injected form instance
$textInput->getValidatorChain()
          ->attach(new CustomValidator($form));

$inputFilter->add($textInput)

//  
$form->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
```

With thi ssettings you should be able to use the form data within your validation class:

```
class CustomValidator {

    private $form;

    public function __construct($form) {
        $this->form = $form;
    }

    public function isValid($value) {

        // Access form data
        $this->form->getData();
    }
}
```